# How to initialize std::string with char* containing null values

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a function that has the following signature

`void serialize(const string& data)`

I have an array of characters with possible null values

```
const char* serializedString
```

(so some characters have the value `'\0'`)

I need to call the given function with the given string!

What I do to achieve that is as following:

```
string messageContents = string(serializedString);
serialize(messageContents.c_str());
```

The problem is the following. The string assigment ignores all characters occuring after the first `'\0'` character.

Even If I call `size()` on the array I get the number of elements before the first `'\0'`.

P.S. I know the 'real' size of the char array (the whole size of the arrray containing the characters including `'\0'` characters)

So how do I call the method correctly?

Comment: Why are you calling `c_str()`?

Comment: Use the two-parameter constructor which takes an explicit `size`. Also, is there any reason why you have to use a `std::string` for this? Sounds like `std::vector` might be more suitable, in a way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Construct the string with the length so it doesn't only contain the characters up to the first `'\0'` i.e.

```
string messageContents = string(serializedString, length);
```

or simply:

```
string messageContents(serializedString, length);
```

And stop calling `c_str()`, `serialize()` takes a string so pass it a string:

```
serialize(messageContents);
```

Otherwise you'll construct a new string from the `const char*`, and that will only read up to the first `'\0'` again.